# How to rotate camera in openscenegraph(Walk Through in Model)?

Tags: c++, openscenegraph

I have loaded 3D Model in my scene and i want to walk through in the world.
i achieved forward,backward,left,right,up and down but i need to rotate my camera at that camera location about x,y,z but i aam not able to get please help me??

```
#include <osgViewer/ViewerEventHandlers>
#include <osgDB/ReadFile>
#include <osgViewer/Viewer>

#include <osg/Camera>



#include <math.h>



osg::Matrixd md ;
osg::Matrixd originalmd ;
osg::Quat qua;
float angle=0;

   osgViewer::Viewer viewer;
   osg::Vec3f eye=osg::Vec3f(1.0,-200.0,2.0);
   osg::Vec3f centre=osg::Vec3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
   osg::Vec3f up=osg::Vec3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);

   osg::Vec3f originaleye=osg::Vec3f(0.0,-200.0,0.0);
   osg::Vec3f originalcentre=osg::Vec3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
   osg::Vec3f originalup=osg::Vec3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);

   int ConstantVariation=5;


class PickHandler : public osgGA::GUIEventHandler 
{
public: 

PickHandler() {}

~PickHandler() {}

bool handle(const osgGA::GUIEventAdapter& ea,osgGA::GUIActionAdapter& aa);


protected:

};

bool PickHandler::handle(const osgGA::GUIEventAdapter&          ea,osgGA::GUIActionAdapter& aa)
{
switch(ea.getEventType())
{
    case(osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::PUSH):
    {
        osgViewer::View* view = dynamic_cast<osgViewer::View*>(&aa);
        //if (view) pick(view,ea);
        return false;
    }    
    case(osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEYDOWN):
    {
        if (ea.getKey()=='c')
        {    
            osgViewer::View* view = dynamic_cast<osgViewer::View*>(&aa);
            osg::ref_ptr<osgGA::GUIEventAdapter> event = new osgGA::GUIEventAdapter(ea);
            event->setX((ea.getXmin()+ea.getXmax())*0.5);
            event->setY((ea.getYmin()+ea.getYmax())*0.5);
           // if (view) pick(view,*event);
        }
        if (ea.getKey()== osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEY_Up)
        {   
            std::cout<<"Forward"<<std::endl;

            md=viewer.getCamera()->getViewMatrix();
            osg::Vec3d trans=md.getTrans();
            std::cout<<"translation="<<trans.x()<<","<<trans.y()<<","<<trans.z()<<std::endl;

            md.getLookAt(eye,centre,up);

            trans.z()=trans.z()+5;

            md.setTrans(trans);
        }
    if (ea.getKey()==osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEY_Down)
        { 
            std::cout<<"BackWard"<<std::endl;  


            md=viewer.getCamera()->getViewMatrix();
            osg::Vec3d trans=md.getTrans();
            std::cout<<"translation="<<trans.x()<<","<<trans.y()<<","<<trans.z()<<std::endl;

            md.getLookAt(eye,centre,up);
            trans.z()=trans.z()-5;

            md.setTrans(trans);

        }
        if (ea.getKey()==osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEY_Left)
        {        

            std::cout<<"LEFT Side"<<std::endl;

            md=viewer.getCamera()->getViewMatrix();
            osg::Vec3d trans=md.getTrans();
            std::cout<<"translation="<<trans.x()<<","<<trans.y()<<","<<trans.z()<<std::endl;

            md.getLookAt(eye,centre,up);

            trans.x()=trans.x()+5;

            md.setTrans(trans);
        }

        if (ea.getKey()==osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEY_Right)
        {        

            std::cout<<"Right Side"<<std::endl;

            md=viewer.getCamera()->getViewMatrix();
            osg::Vec3d trans = md.getTrans();
            std::cout<<"translation="<<trans.x()<<","<<trans.y()<<","<<trans.z()<<std::endl;

            trans.x()=trans.x()-5;
            md.setTrans(trans);


        }
        if(ea.getKey()==osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEY_Page_Up)
        {
            std::cout<<"UP"<<std::endl;

            md=viewer.getCamera()->getViewMatrix();
            osg::Vec3d trans = md.getTrans();
            std::cout<<"translation="<<trans.x()<<","<<trans.y()<<","<<trans.z()<<std::endl;

            trans.y()=trans.y()-5;
            md.setTrans(trans);


        }

        if(ea.getKey()==osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEY_Page_Down)
        {
            std::cout<<"Down"<<std::endl;

            md=viewer.getCamera()->getViewMatrix();
            osg::Vec3d trans = md.getTrans();
            std::cout<<"translation="<<trans.x()<<","<<trans.y()<<","<<trans.z()<<std::endl;

            trans.y()=trans.y()+5;
            md.setTrans(trans);


        }

        if(ea.getKey()==osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEY_8)
        {
            std::cout<<"Rotation"<<std::endl;
            md=viewer.getCamera()->getViewMatrix();
            osg::Vec3d trans=md.getTrans();
            double a=trans.x();
            double b=trans.y();
            double c=trans.z();
            std::cout<<"translation="<<trans.x()<<","<<trans.y()<<","<<trans.z()<<std::endl;
            md.setTrans(osg::Vec3d(0,0,0));
            std::cout<<"translation="<<trans.x()<<","<<trans.y()<<","<<trans.z()<<std::endl;

            angle=0.077;
            //osg::Quat qa(angle,osg::Vec3d(0.0,0.0,1.0));

            md.getLookAt(eye,centre,up);
            osg::Quat qa(angle,up);
            md.setRotate(qa);
            up=md.getRotate()*trans;

            md.setRotate(qa);
            trans.x()=a;
            trans.y()=b;
            trans.z()=c;
            md.setTrans(trans);

            std::cout<<"translation="<<trans.x()<<","<<trans.y()<<","<<trans.z()<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<" End Rotation"<<std::endl;
        }           


        if(ea.getKey()==osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEY_Space)
        {
            md=originalmd;

        }
        return false;
    }    
    default:
        return false;
 }
}



int main( int argc, char **argv )
{



osg::ref_ptr<osg::Group> scene = new  osg::Group;

scene->addChild(osgDB::readNodeFile("cessna.osg"));

viewer.addEventHandler(new osgViewer::WindowSizeHandler);
viewer.addEventHandler(new PickHandler());

viewer.setSceneData(scene.get());

const osg::BoundingSphere& bs = scene->getBound();


viewer.getCamera()->setViewMatrixAsLookAt(bs.center()+osg::Vec3(0.0f, -(3*bs.radius()),0.0f), bs.center(), osg::Z_AXIS) ;

md=viewer.getCamera()->getViewMatrix();
originalmd=md;



viewer.realize();

while(!viewer.done())
{
    viewer.getCamera()->setViewMatrix(md);
    viewer.frame();
 }


}
```

**Edited:-
I am having doubt that whether am performing task in proper way i.e i need to move camera but above code translate and rotate object to feel that camera is rotated...many websites says that in opengl there is no camera link(https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm).**

Comment: Have you looked through the different manipulators that come with osg? (They're found in the osgManipulator module.) Sometimes there's no point recoding the wheel.

Comment: ya i tried all manipulators in osg but the default values of camera motion are not adjustable for my model..so  i am trying to write walk through so that it would be generic for all models by changing offset values in x,y,z directions

Comment: can you please help me to install OpensceneGraph on Ubuntu.. i am struggling, don't know where to start and where it will end

Comment: http://trac.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg//wiki/Support/GettingStarted @ Irfan Ghaffar7

Answer (score 0):

Just like for translation you are getting the existing translation using `getTrans()` and adding an increment or decrement to it, similarly for rotation also get the existing rotation using `getRotate()` and then add a small increment or decrement to it, don't directly set it to the same value every time.

Comment: after geting rotation value i tried to set rotation by using function setrotate(osg::quat) but it takes quaternion as argument.i donot have idea how to set exact quaternion to set...

Answer (score 0):

performing as i needed but can i do much better than this..

```
#include <osgViewer/ViewerEventHandlers>
#include <osgDB/ReadFile>
#include <osgViewer/Viewer>

#include <osg/Camera>



 #include <math.h>




// class to handle events with a pick


osg::Matrixd md ;
osg::Matrixd originalmd ;
osg::Quat qua;
float angle=0;

   osgViewer::Viewer viewer;
   osg::Vec3f eye=osg::Vec3f(0.0,-200.0,0.0);
   osg::Vec3f centre=osg::Vec3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
   osg::Vec3f up=osg::Vec3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);

   osg::Vec3f originaleye=osg::Vec3f(0.0,-200.0,0.0);
   osg::Vec3f originalcentre=osg::Vec3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
   osg::Vec3f originalup=osg::Vec3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);

   int ConstantVariation=5;


  class PickHandler : public osgGA::GUIEventHandler {
  public: 

  PickHandler() {}

  ~PickHandler() {}

  bool handle(const osgGA::GUIEventAdapter& ea,osgGA::GUIActionAdapter& aa);


protected:

 };

bool PickHandler::handle(const osgGA::GUIEventAdapter&   ea,osgGA::GUIActionAdapter& aa)
{
   switch(ea.getEventType())
   {
       case(osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::PUSH):
      {
         osgViewer::View* view = dynamic_cast<osgViewer::View*>(&aa);
         //if (view) pick(view,ea);
         return false;
     }    
    case(osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEYDOWN):
    {
        if (ea.getKey()=='c')
        {    
            osgViewer::View* view = dynamic_cast<osgViewer::View*>(&aa);
            osg::ref_ptr<osgGA::GUIEventAdapter> event = new osgGA::GUIEventAdapter(ea);
            event->setX((ea.getXmin()+ea.getXmax())*0.5);
            event->setY((ea.getYmin()+ea.getYmax())*0.5);
           // if (view) pick(view,*event);
        }
        if (ea.getKey()== osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEY_Up)
        {   
            std::cout<<"Forward"<<std::endl;

            md=viewer.getCamera()->getViewMatrix();
            md.getLookAt(eye,centre,up);

            osg::Vec3f actuallook=centre-eye;

            actuallook=actuallook/(actuallook.length());


            eye=eye+((actuallook)*10);
            centre=centre+((actuallook)*10);

            viewer.getCamera()->setViewMatrixAsLookAt(eye, centre, osg::Z_AXIS) ;
        }
    if (ea.getKey()==osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEY_Down)
        { 
            std::cout<<"BackWard"<<std::endl;  


            md=viewer.getCamera()->getViewMatrix();
            md.getLookAt(eye,centre,up);

            osg::Vec3f actuallook=centre-eye;

            actuallook=actuallook/(actuallook.length());


            eye=eye-((actuallook)*10);

            viewer.getCamera()->setViewMatrixAsLookAt(eye, centre, osg::Vec3d(up.x(),up.y(),up.z())) ;

        }
        if (ea.getKey()==osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEY_Left)
        {        

            std::cout<<"LEFT Side"<<std::endl;

            md=viewer.getCamera()->getViewMatrix();
            osg::Vec3d trans=md.getTrans();
            std::cout<<"translation="<<trans.x()<<","<<trans.y()<<","<<trans.z()<<std::endl;

            md.getLookAt(eye,centre,up);

            trans.x()=trans.x()+10;

            md.setTrans(trans);

            viewer.getCamera()->setViewMatrix(md);
        }

        if (ea.getKey()==osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEY_Right)
        {        

            std::cout<<"Right Side"<<std::endl;

            md=viewer.getCamera()->getViewMatrix();
            osg::Vec3d trans = md.getTrans();
            std::cout<<"translation="<<trans.x()<<","<<trans.y()<<","<<trans.z()<<std::endl;

            trans.x()=trans.x()-10;
            md.setTrans(trans);

            viewer.getCamera()->setViewMatrix(md);


        }
        if(ea.getKey()==osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEY_Page_Up)
        {
            std::cout<<"UP"<<std::endl;

            md=viewer.getCamera()->getViewMatrix();
            osg::Vec3d trans = md.getTrans();
            std::cout<<"translation="<<trans.x()<<","<<trans.y()<<","<<trans.z()<<std::endl;

            trans.y()=trans.y()-10;
            md.setTrans(trans);

            viewer.getCamera()->setViewMatrix(md);


        }

        if(ea.getKey()==osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEY_Page_Down)
        {
            std::cout<<"Down"<<std::endl;

            md=viewer.getCamera()->getViewMatrix();
            osg::Vec3d trans = md.getTrans();
            std::cout<<"translation="<<trans.x()<<","<<trans.y()<<","<<trans.z()<<std::endl;

            trans.y()=trans.y()+10;
            md.setTrans(trans);

            viewer.getCamera()->setViewMatrix(md);


        }
        if(ea.getKey()==osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEY_7)
        {
            std::cout<<"Rotation"<<std::endl;
            md=viewer.getCamera()->getViewMatrix();


            angle=(3.142/180)*2;

            md.getLookAt(eye,centre,up);
            std::cout<<"up="<<up.x()<<up.y()<<up.z()<<std::endl;

            osg::Vec3f actuallook=centre-eye;
            actuallook=actuallook/(actuallook.length());

            osg::Quat qa(-angle,osg::Vec3f(up.x(),up.y(),up.z()));

            osg::Vec3f look= (qa * actuallook);
            look=look/(look.length());
            centre = eye+(look*actuallook.length());

            viewer.getCamera()->setViewMatrixAsLookAt(eye, centre, osg::Vec3d(up.x(),up.y(),up.z())) ;
            std::cout<<"up="<<up.x()<<up.y()<<up.z()<<std::endl;

            std::cout<<" End Rotation"<<std::endl;
        }

        if(ea.getKey()==osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEY_8)
        {
            std::cout<<"Rotation"<<std::endl;
            md=viewer.getCamera()->getViewMatrix();


            angle=(3.142/180)*2;

            md.getLookAt(eye,centre,up);
            std::cout<<"up="<<up.x()<<up.y()<<up.z()<<std::endl;

            osg::Vec3f actuallook=centre-eye;
            actuallook=actuallook/(actuallook.length());

            osg::Quat qa(angle,osg::Vec3f(up.x(),up.y(),up.z()));

            osg::Vec3f look= (qa * actuallook);
            look=look/(look.length());
            centre = eye+(look*actuallook.length());

            viewer.getCamera()->setViewMatrixAsLookAt(eye, centre, osg::Vec3d(up.x(),up.y(),up.z())) ;
            std::cout<<"up="<<up.x()<<up.y()<<up.z()<<std::endl;

            std::cout<<" End Rotation"<<std::endl;
        }           


        if(ea.getKey()==osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KEY_Space)
        {
            md=originalmd;
            viewer.getCamera()->setViewMatrix(originalmd);

        }
        return false;
    }    
    default:
        return false;
}
}



int main( int argc, char **argv )
 {



osg::ref_ptr<osg::Group> scene = new  osg::Group;

//scene->addChild(osgDB::readNodeFile("F:\\Fantasy Mall\\Fantasy Mall\\Fantasy_Mall.obj"));

scene->addChild(osgDB::readNodeFile("cessna.osg"));

viewer.addEventHandler(new osgViewer::WindowSizeHandler);
viewer.addEventHandler(new PickHandler());

viewer.setSceneData(scene.get());

const osg::BoundingSphere& bs = scene->getBound();


viewer.getCamera()->setViewMatrixAsLookAt(bs.center()+osg::Vec3(0.0f, -(3*bs.radius()),0.0f), bs.center(), osg::Z_AXIS) ;

md=viewer.getCamera()->getViewMatrix();
originalmd=md;



viewer.realize();

while(!viewer.done())
{

    //viewer.getCamera()->setViewMatrix(md);
    viewer.frame();
}


}
```

Comment: Is there any difference from this code to the code in your question? It isn't clear.